# Deep learning: Loss change dramatically every epoch

Tags: deep-learning

I am using Keras for building a Siamese neural network, two inputs have the following format:

```
x[:, 0]: shape is (20000, 600), each array looks like [12, 23, 3, 16...0, 0, 0...]

x[:, 1]: shape is (20000, 600), each array looks like [7832, 12342, 8976, 1642...0, 0, 0...]

model.fit([x[:, 0],x[:, 1]], y, batch_size=64, nb_epoch=10)
```

After I used the fit function, the loss would changed dramatically.

```
Epoch 1/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s - loss:26157091.5761
Epoch 2/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 26103.3771
Epoch 3/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 66322.9797
Epoch 4/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 33068.0571
Epoch 5/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 3271.2368
Epoch 6/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 124758.9755
Epoch 7/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 11452.0805
Epoch 8/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 31291.7847
Epoch 9/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 2562.3131
Epoch 10/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.4973
* Accuracy on training set: 50.00%
Epoch 1/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 23972822.8330
Epoch 2/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 31353.3295
Epoch 3/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 33149.6620
Epoch 4/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 22481.5665
Epoch 5/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 103161.4879
Epoch 6/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 11121.0753
Epoch 7/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 122371.6265
Epoch 8/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 49855.2024
Epoch 9/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 41485.7752
Epoch 10/10
20000/20000 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 2243.4557
* Accuracy on training set: 50.05%
......
```

I am thinking of this issue possibly was caused by the difference of x[:,0] and x[:,1] though they have same shape and same dimension.

Do I need to do the normalization to make two inputs into the same range( like 0 to 1)?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518656/how-to-interpret-loss-and-accuracy-for-a-machine-learning-model
How is the network initialized? Randomly? If it is the case, it seems logical to mt to have a huge loss between the first and second epoch.
An increasing loss means that the "adjustments" the net did, bring it further from its "optimal" solution but as you see, when this happens, the next epoch the loss decreases again.

Comment: @Eskapp, Thanks. I am using the example here with my own data: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py, I think the network was initialized randomly.

Comment: "I have couple files" -> what do the files contain?

Comment: Each file contains training data, I am updating the question, you might understand my question clearly.